# How can I search for a very large number of short text strings in a larger string using excel?

Tags: excel, bioinformatics

I am working with a dataset containing 763508 text strings about 8 characters in length and want to locate these strings in a set containing 277 strings each 500 characters long. It is important that my return values indicate which of the short strings occur, how many times they occur, and where they occur in the 500 character strings. I understand that this is a fairly complex task so any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

---

Just to add a bit of context to this question I am working with expression data and am looking at TF binding sites present in a set of differentially expressed genes. Although it would theoretically be easier to just do MEME analysis on MEME-suite, MEME data is challenging to export, format, and analyze in a way that is useful to me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: How is your sheet laid out? Does each one of the 763508 text strings have it's own cell and the 277 strings have their own cell as well?

Comment: Yes. On both sheets I have all strings in their own cells.

Comment: You will likely need to use VBA - are you familiar with that?

Comment: Please do not use Excel for bioinformatics.

Comment: You might want to look into R. There is a [bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/) community with a rich set of tools to work with bio* data. Welcome! p.s. Oh, Python can handle some stuff, too.

Comment: I am not? Is it fairly intuitive to use?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty basic and may be slowish...

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim needles, haystacks, h, n, i As Long, j As Long, p As Long
    Dim rDest As Range

    'short sequences in sheet 1 ColA (no gaps)
    needles = Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Value

    'longer sequences in sheet 2 ColA (no gaps)
    haystacks = Sheets(2).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Value

    'start recording hits here
    Set rDest = Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    For i = 1 To UBound(haystacks, 1)
        h = haystacks(i, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(needles, 1)
            n = needles(j, 1)
            p = InStr(1, h, n)
            'loop while have a hit
            Do While p > 0
                rDest.Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(i, n, p)
                Set rDest = rDest.Offset(1, 0)
                p = InStr(p + 1, h, n)
            Loop
        Next
    Next i

End Sub
```

If you expect a lot of hits then writing them line-by-line may slow you down and that part could be optimized to be faster.